# Ajax cross application on same machine

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, nginx

I have 2 applications running on the same machine:

- node.js app running on port 15000
- a full javascript application running on port 15001

Both are served through nginx front end (each app defined as a virtual host)

Ajax requests from the javascript app (requesting resources from the node.js app) are not working.

Is this linked to restriction of Ajax for cross domain ? The domain is the same (only the port are differents).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ports are seen as a different domains.

[MDC Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, limiting requests on same domain to different port

**Same origin policy**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy